# How to add an arbitrary line to Seaborn.Objects plot

Tags: python, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

Is there a way using seaborn objects to add arbitrary line into a plot? Something like `ggplot`s `geom_abline` specifying `slope` and `intercept`?  I mean, using seaborn objects API only. ...

```
# this DOES NOT WORK
(
   so.Plot(df, x="var1",y="var2")
        .add(so.Dot())
        .add(so.Line(color="black"), slope=1, intercept=1) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newermind, I've solved this one. There is no that simple solution in Seaborn 0.12. You need to go into matplotlib.

So, I've implemented the Mark for you - `so.Axline()`. And I've added two more `so.Axvline()` and `so.Axhline()`. To enrich the functionality, there are some more changes (adding `so.AggCustom()` etc.).

**It has not been merged yet.** See [the PR link](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/3261) for reference. The code implementing those objects is to be found therein.

Answer (score 0):

We can pass new data to a layer. Something like below should work.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn.objects as so

intercept = 1
slope = 1

(
   so.Plot(df, x="var1",y="var2")
        .add(so.Dot())
        .add(so.Line(), 
             data=pd.DataFrame({'x':np.arange(100)})
             .assign(y=lambda dat:intercept+slope*dat['x']),
             x='x', y='y'
            )
)
```